# Memory leak when when using readRDS in a loop?

Tags: r

Memory is exploding when I'm looping through a large collection of RDS files. Running garbage collection on each iteration does not help.

```r
library(rnaturalearth)
library(purrr)
library(glue)

world <- ne_countries(scale = "large", returnclass = "sf")

walk(1:1000, function(i) {
  saveRDS(world, file = glue("cache/{i}.rds"))
}, .progress = TRUE)

walk(1:1000, function(i) {
  world <- readRDS(glue("cache/{i}.rds"))
}, .progress = TRUE)
```

Memory usage was monitored using the macOS activity monitor and the RStudio memory widget. This is `gc()` before and after:

```
> gc()
          used (Mb) gc trigger  (Mb) limit (Mb) max used (Mb)
Ncells 1075674 57.5    2266002 121.1         NA  1281588 68.5
Vcells 1655548 12.7    8388608  64.0     102400  2572972 19.7
                                                   
> gc()
          used (Mb) gc trigger   (Mb) limit (Mb)   max used   (Mb)
Ncells 1183433 63.3   17322119  925.2         NA   23685502 1265.0
Vcells 2534823 19.4  791702570 6040.3     102400 1137590813 8679.2
```

Comment: You don't show how you measured memory use.

Answer (score 2):

I also see signs of a leak when I run your code, but I don't think it happens in `readRDS` or `saveRDS`.  If I modify your code to this:

```
gc()

for (i in 1:100) 
  saveRDS(world, file = paste0("cache/", i, ".rds"))

gc()

for (i in 1:100)
  world <- readRDS(paste0("cache/", i, ".rds"))

gc()
```

the leak goes away.  So it appears to be in `glue()` or `walk()` instead.  I'm currently running the test with `glue()` but not `walk()`, and I'll update when done.  (Things are slow on my laptop.)

Update:  I don't see a leak when I restore `glue()`.  So that suggests the leak is in `walk()`.  But when I remove everything and just run this code:

```
library(purrr)

gc()

walk(1:1000, function(i) {
  Sys.sleep(i/10000)
}, .progress = TRUE)

gc()
```

I don't see the leak.  So there's some sort of interaction going on, but I'm not sure what it is.